# signal uncorrelated with delta in the origin

Tags: autocorrelation

I have a stochastic process completely uncorrelated. Why the autocorrelation function has a delta of dirac in the origin?
Which is the reason of that?

$R_{XX}({\tau})=A{\delta(\tau)}$

where $R_{XX}$ is the autocorrelation function of $X$ process and $A$ is a constant dependent by process spectrum

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has a delta at the origin because you are multiplying your time series with itself (i.e. there is no time delay).  Any non-zero time series correlated with itself will give a positive value.

Answer (score 1):

As you noted, the wide-sense stationary stochastic process $X(t)$ is uncorrelated with itself for all nonzero time lags $\tau$. For $\tau=0$, it's impossible for a process to be uncorrelated with itself (unless $X(t)$ is the trivial process $X(t)=0$). Look at the definition for $R_{XX}(\tau)$:

$$
R_{XX}(\tau) = E(X(t)X^*(t+\tau)
$$

$$
R_{XX}(0) = E(|X(t)|^2)
$$

By definition, $|X(t)|^2$ must be $\ge 0$, so its expectation must also satisfy that condition.